# Tradução da medalha Eleitorado

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Eu acho que a tradução da medalha [Eleitorado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) não é bem clara... eu já me debatí uma vez com isso no [MetaEN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195160/description-for-electorate-badge) e confesso que desistí por não ser nativo em Inglês, mas aqui não deixo passar sem vos perguntar.

A descrição atual é:

> **Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram em perguntas.**

Sugiro algumas versões mais claras (na minha opinião).
Se alguém achar útil pode colocar uma delas como resposta ou uma nova. Se houver consenso mudo a tag da pergunta para tradução e tentamos mudar.

> Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos atríbuídos foram à pergunta.
>
> Votou em 600 posts e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram em perguntas.
>
> Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram na própria pergunta.
>
> Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais, entre pergunta e resposta, foram em perguntas.

Comment: Sergio, o que você acha confuso? Concordo com o mgibsonbr, acho clara a formulação atual. Suas formulações alternativas têm problemas (exceto a última).

Comment: @bfavaretto eu acho confuso a primeira vez que aparece a palavra `perguntas` que na verdade quer dizer "post"/publicação e na segunda quer dizer a parte do post onde está a pergunta. Sei que o nome pergunta nesse primeiro caso diz respeito a post. O que eu gostava de conseguir expressar melhor é a diferença de siginficado entre as duas palavras `perguntas`. Se eu tentar explicar/referir o significado da segunda palavra diría: Refere-se à pergunta da pergunta, e isso soa estranho.

Comment: Eu acho que você entendeu errado a regra da medalha. "Pergunta" sempre quer dizer pergunta mesmo. Para ganhar a medalha, você precisa ter votado em 600 perguntas (os votos em respostas não contam), e o total de votos em perguntas não pode ser menor que 25% de todos os seus votos (perguntas + respostas).

Comment: @bfavaretto, ok. O problema está na minha leitura. Têm razão, como está (ou a minha última opção) está correcta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram em perguntas.**

Minha opinião é que assim está claro o suficiente, não há necessidade de mudança. Vamos ver o que os demais acham.

Sobre as alternativas:

> Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos atríbuídos foram à pergunta.

Qual pergunta?

> Votou em 600 posts e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram em perguntas.

Não corresponde ao comportamento da medalha. Os 600 votos devem de fato ter sido em perguntas.

> Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram na própria pergunta.

De novo, qual é a "própria pergunta"? (aliás, um usuário não vota nos próprios posts...)

> Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais, entre pergunta e resposta, foram em perguntas.

Correto. Se for adotada uma descrição alternativa, essa seria a mais apropriada (a menos que alguém tenha uma sugestão melhor).

---

Exemplo sobre as regras da medalha:

```
┌───────────┬──────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────────────────┐  
│ Perguntas │ Respostas│ Total │   %   │  Medalha atribuída? │  
├───────────┼──────────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────┤  
│       600 │     2400 │  3000 │   20% │  Não: % muito baixa │  
│       201 │      401 │   602 │  ~33% │ Não; < 600 perguntas│  
│       599 │        0 │   599 │  100% │ Não; < 600 perguntas│  
│       600 │        0 │   600 │  100% │                  Sim│  
│       500 │      500 │  1000 │   50% │ Não; < 600 perguntas│  
│       650 │      650 │  1300 │   50% │                  Sim│  
└───────────┴──────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

Agora entendi. Ficaria mais claro assim:

**25% ou mais dos votos totais foram em perguntas e votou em mais de 600 perguntas**

Esse tem erro de concordância:

**Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram em perguntas.**

Pois 'votos totais' não dá a entender que é a soma de votos em perguntas e respostas.

Comment: A versão em inglês é assim: `Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions`. É também não muito claro?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal acho que não ta claro, se tivesse não estariamos falando sobre isso aqui, quando eu li eu não entendi, então acho que nao ta claro

Comment: Você só alterou a ordem das sentenças, mas para mim fez toda a diferença, pois "votos totais" vindo primeiro fica claro que são votos tanto em perguntas como em respostas. Só tiraria o "mais" em "mais de 600 perguntas", pois 600 já são o suficiente, não é preciso de 601.

Comment: Se trocasse somente "dos votos totais" para "do total de votos", você acharia mais claro?

Comment: @bfavaretto não muda mt, inverter a ordem da frase fica melhor