# A descrição da medalha "Eleitorado" está esquisita

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Pelo que entendi lendo [este post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/953/6036) para ganhar a medalha **Eleitorado** é necessário votar em 600 perguntas e que de todos os seus votos pelo menos 25% seja também em perguntas.

No entanto, a descrição que aparece pra mim é a seguinte:

> Vote 600 vezes, com pelo menos 25% dos votos indo para perguntas

Que para mim quer dizer outra coisa: para ganhar eu preciso ter votado no mínimo 600 vezes e preciso que 25% dos meus votos sejam em perguntas. Neste caso, o acompanhamento fica estranho, porque não interessaria o número de votos em perguntas e sim o número total de votos.

Será que eu to viajando? :P

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só pra comentar, algumas medalhas no SOen tem uma descrição ruim.

Comment: Acredito que sim. Exclusivamente essa pergunta eu achei ok a descrição no SOen: `Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions` Está análoga à sugestão do bigown.

Comment: Sim, posso estar enganado, mas as tags foram importadas do SOen no final de 2013, na época se eu não me engano as tags em inglês também estavam erradas, elas foram corrigidas somente depois.

Comment: Saquei. É engraçado que já em 2014, a resposta aceita da pergunta que linkei aí foi: `Votou em 600 perguntas e 25% ou mais dos votos totais foram em perguntas.` Será que nunca mudou, ou mudou recentemente?

Comment: Pode ser, como disse não me lembro ao certo, faz bastante tempo :)

Comment: @DanielFalbel consegue confirmar se está ok?

Comment: @bigown aqui ainda não mudou...

Comment: @bigown Agora foi!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Que tal?

> Vote em 600 perguntas, com pelo menos 25% dos votos totais indo para perguntas

Sugeri essa tradução e espero que outra pessoa com privilégio de revisão aprove. Não sei se ficará ruim pelo tamanho do texto que cresceu, aí terei que editar. Se tiverem outra sugestão é só dizer que eu mudo lá.

Tem que aguardar para entrar no sistema.

Lembrando que todos podem sugerir traduções no [Transifex do SOpt](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/).

Comment: Legal! não sabia do Transifex!